# Spring boot api to Update list of product stock by different itemcode(unique id)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, sql-update

**Below is my database table before performing update operation**

| id | item_name | item_code | stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xyz | 100 | 150 |
| 2 | xyz | 101 | 50 |
| 3 | xyz | 102 | 100 |
| 4 | xyz | 103 | 48 |
| 5 | xyz | 104 | 59 |
| 6 | xyz | 105 | 50 |

**This is my Controller**

```
@PutMapping("/updateMultipleStock")
public ResponseEntity<?> updateMultipleStockByitemCode(@RequestBody List<Items> items) {
return service.updateMultipleStockByitemCode(items);
}
```

**Service class**

```
  @Override
  public ResponseEntity<?> updateMultipleStockByitemCode(List<Items> items) 
 {
 for (Items item : items) {
  repository.updateMultipleStockByitemCode(item.getStock(), item.getItemCode(),
 datetime);
  }
  return new ResponseEntity<Object>(items, HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

**Repository**

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("update Items i set i.stock=:stock,i.updatedDate=:date WHERE i.itemCode=:itemcode")
void updateMultipleStockByitemCode(@Param("itemcode") Integer itemCode,
  @Param("stock") Integer stock, @Param("date") LocalDateTime datetime);
```

**Request body will looks likes this**

```
[
{
"itemCode": 100,
"stock": 5
},
{
"itemCode": 102,
"stock": 3
},
{
"itemCode": 104,
"stock": 2
}
]
```

I wanted to update the stocks by item codes ,data base should be update as below once after performing put operation by sent above request body.

**minus the stock(getting in request body) with database stock** example : stocks for item code 100 should updated as 145  , 102 should updated as 97 , 104 should updated as 46

And how can I validated item codes is present or not in database

| id | item_name | item_code | stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xyz | 100 | 145 |
| 2 | xyz | 101 | 50 |
| 3 | xyz | 102 | 97 |
| 4 | xyz | 103 | 46 |
| 5 | xyz | 104 | 59 |
| 6 | xyz | 105 | 50 |

Please give me a solution How can this be done ?? What is the logics should be used in service class
Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: Your Service and Controller class code looks same.

Comment: Sorry i added wrong code , now i edited the code please check now @GauravJeswani

Comment: What problem you are facing here? Is it like for 100 itemcode it's getting updated to 5 rather than 145?

Comment: yes @GauravJeswani Exactly and i wanted to validate items code is present or not in database

Comment: And what you want to do if ItemCode is not present in DB?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using JPQL you need to make a little update to your query. Replace `i.stock=:stock` with `i.stock=(i.stock - :stock)` in your code.

And to find out if `itemcode` is present in DB or not, you can change the return type to int. So if records is present it will return value greater than 0 (count of updated records). If there is no matching `itemcode` it will return 0.

Updated code will look like this:

**RepoCode:**

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("update Items i set i.stock=(i.stock - :stock), i.updatedDate=:date WHERE i.itemCode=:itemcode")
int updateMultipleStockByitemCode(@Param("itemcode") Integer itemCode,
  @Param("stock") Integer stock, @Param("date") LocalDateTime datetime);
```

**Service Code:**

```
@Override
  public ResponseEntity<?> updateMultipleStockByitemCode(List<Items> items) 
 {
 for (Items item : items) {
  int updatedRecordsCount = repository.updateMultipleStockByitemCode(item.getStock(), item.getItemCode(),
 datetime);
  if(updatedRecordsCount == 0) {
     // itemcode not found
  } 

  }
  return new ResponseEntity<Object>(items, HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Gaurav Jeswani Query  is working now 
Can u please tell where should i change return type exactly

Comment: I have already updated that in your query response. Change void to int in query return type. And see the updated service code in answer.

Comment: but i wanted to show error message if any one of the itemcode is invalid before updating table, update should be performed only if all the items codes present in database

Comment: Then simply throw exception if for any record recordCount is 0 in response. And your complete transaction will be rolled back. No record will be updated. Else create another query to check if all records exists or not.